# Can I go to Venezuela from USA, using a Brazilian passport?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, dual-nationality, venezuela, brazilian-citizens

I was born here in America, but I also have my citizenship from Brazil. I have *both* passports, dual-nationality. I know for a fact that Brazilians **do not need a visa** to enter Venezuela. I also **do not have a visa to USA, Brazil, or Venezuela**. I simply use my passport to USA and Brazil.

**Can I leave America, use my Brazilian passport to enter Venezuela?**

If so, **how would I come back home to America?** I have my thoughts on how but I'm unsure, *please correct me if I'm wrong.*

1. Will Venezuela allow me to come back if I show them both my passport? ...and no visa.
2. Do I just show my Brazilian passport? If so, won't they ask me for a visa to USA?
3. Will I have to make a trip to Brazil then USA?

If anyone knows of someone or an office, anything that I can call (in the USA) please give me that number!

Comment: As far as I know the US doesn't do exit control, you won't have a problem leaving on a different passport, but you must enter with your American passport

Comment: When you leave the US, show the airline your Brazilian passport. When you arrive in Venezuela, show your Brazilian passport to immigration. When you depart Venezuela, show your US passport to the airline, and show your Brazilian passport to immigration. When you arrive in the US, show your US passport.

Comment: Technically not a duplicate, although the linked question is very informative.

Comment: When departing Venezuela and showing them my US passport to the airline won't they ask for a visa? @MichaelHampton

Comment: @KendraA No, because your US passport entitles you to enter the US! The airline cares about your _destination_ country, the immigration cares about the country you are standing in.

Comment: Are you sure this can work? Is there anything I should be worried about? Thank you soo much!! @MichaelHampton

Comment: Yes, dual citizens do this all the time. It's no problem :)